# Async call adapter show nothing

Tags: android, android-asynctask, adapter

I have a problem.
I´m set an adapter when a `asyctask` end. 
All code rules but when the code is inflated the screen keep white. The code dont throw any exception and i put some log to control execution flow. All is ok but the screen keep white. 
I´m doing that:

```
protected class ObtenerCursos extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    private JSONArray resultado;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private Activity_Mis_Curso activity;
    List <Curso> lista;

    public ObtenerCursos(Activity_Mis_Curso misCursos){
        this.activity=misCursos;
    }
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        resultado = getCursos(url,usuario);
        if (resultado != null) {
            lista=parseJSONDocumentos(resultado);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Activity_Mis_Curso.this,
                "Obteniendo cursos", "Espere por favor...", true);

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        dialog.cancel();
        if (result) {
            gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.miscursos_Grid);
            if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                gridView.setNumColumns(3);
                numColumns = 3;
            } else {
                numColumns = 2;
                gridView.setNumColumns(2);
            }
            gridView.setAdapter(new MisCursosAdapter(Activity_Mis_Curso.this, listaCursos, numColumns));
            gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    if (listaCursos.get(position).getSoloReproduccion() == 0) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(Activity_Mis_Curso.this,
                                Activity_Main_Tradicional.class);
                        i.putExtra("Curso", listaCursos.get(position));
                        finish();
                        startActivity(i);
                    } else {
                        Intent i = new Intent(Activity_Mis_Curso.this,
                                Activity_Curso_SoloReproductor.class);
                        i.putExtra("Curso", listaCursos.get(position));
                        finish();
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                }
            });
            Log.e("ando", "por aqui \n\n");
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No se han encontrado cursos",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent in = new Intent(Activity_Mis_Curso.this,
                    Activity_Index.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(in);
        }

    }
}
```

I can´t find where is my problem, i don´t know what i´m doing bad.

Comment: Why you set your adapter inside the async task? Isn't better if you just set the data on your post execute code and the adapter before you call your task?

Comment: what is `numColumns` ?

Comment: NumColums is the number of columna that i ser yo gridView.

Comment: I try to serñt the adapter before execute asyctask. I set adapter con postexecute because i have to pass the arrayList whit the adapter... If not the arraylist on the adapter is empty no? I'm not sure